# Database "test" is being updated or update was not complited

Tags: basex

I am using BaseX version 9.0.5 There was some update operation was going on but now I am not able to do anything with the database nether read operation nor write operation.

I am getting the message "Database "test" is being updated or update was not completed" if I am trying to open the database

Can anyone suggest how can i resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error message suggests that there might be some ongoing update operation on the "test" database or the previous update operation might not have completed successfully.

Here are a few steps that you can try to resolve this issue:

**Check if the update operation is still ongoing**: Run the "info" command in BaseX console to check if the update operation is still running. If it is running, wait until it is completed.

**Forcefully stop the update operation**: If the update operation is not running or if it is stuck, try stopping it forcefully. To do this, run the "stop" command in BaseX console followed by the name of the database. For example, "stop test". This should stop the ongoing update operation.

**Check if the database is locked**: If you are still unable to perform any operation on the database, check if the database is locked. Run the "check" command in BaseX console followed by the name of the database. For example, "check test". This should display the status of the database. If the database is locked, you can unlock it by running the "unlock" command followed by the name of the database. For example, "unlock test".

**Restart BaseX**: If none of the above steps work, try restarting BaseX and then try accessing the database again.